# How to take hyperlinks from a wikipedia page

Tags: python, hyperlink, wikipedia, wiki

My current project requires to obtain the summaries of some wikipedia pages. This is really easy to do, but I want to make a general script for that. More specifically I also want to obtain the summaries of  hyperlinks. For example I want to get the summary of this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_industries (this is easy). Moreover, I would also like to get the summaries of the hyperlinks in Section: Definitions -> 'Advertising', 'Marketing', 'Architecture',...,'visual arts'. My problem is that some of these hyperlinks have different page names. For example, the previous mentioned page has the hyperlink 'Software' (number 6), but I want the summary of the page, which is 'Software Engineering'.
Can someone help me with that? I can find the summaries of the pages with the same hyperlink name, but that is not always the case. So basically I am looking for a way to use (page.links) to only one area of the page.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Don't they have an API so you don't need to use web scraping?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  You need to do your research on how to scrape information from web pages, including picking out tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Beautiful soup, this will print all the links with the given prefix

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, re
''' Dont forget to install/setup package = 'lxml' '''



url = "your link"

response = requests.get(url)

data = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')

tags = soup.find_all('a')

''' This will print every available link'''

for tag in tags:                       
    print(tag.get('href'))

''' this will print links with only prefix as given'''
for link in soup.find_all('a',attrs={'href': re.compile("^{{you prefix here}}")}):
    print(link.get('href')
```